# When can 叫 be used saying that someone is calling someone and when for asking a name?

Tags: usage, meaning-in-context

From [The HSK acadamy site](http://www.hsk.academy/en/characters/%E5%8F%AB), it seems that 叫 can be used in two contexts.

First, it can be used to say someone called someone else:

> 1. 妈妈和爸爸叫我

There is no translation given, but I think it means *mum and dad call me*.

In the second and third examples on this page,

> 2. 我的名字叫李明
> 3. 小姐，你叫什么名字？

I think 叫 is here used for giving or asking someones name. I would translate the second sentence as *My name is* 李明, and the third as *Lady, what is your name?* However, this is always used together with 名字, which means name. However, I've also seen simply

> 4. 我叫 Wythagoras

for simply *my name is Wythagoras* (not my real name, by the way).

I am a bit confused by all the different usages of 叫, so the question is: In what context can 叫 be used for saying that someone is calling someone (as in the first sentence) and when for asking a name, when should 名字 be used with 叫 and when can it be left out?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> http://www.cantonese.sheik.co.uk/dictionary/characters/339/
>
> **叫**
>
> [1] [v] cry; shout; hail; scream
>
> [2] [v] **be called**; known as
>
> [3] [v] **call**; summon
>
> [4] [v] cause

**叫** [3]. **call**

- 你叫我 = you call me.
- **我叫彼得 = I call Peter**

**叫** [2]. **be called**

- 这叫工作 = this is called work
- **我叫彼得 = I am called Peter** (My name is Peter)

Notice 我叫彼得 could mean "I call Peter" or "I am called Peter"(my name is Peter)

To avoid confusion. When you use 叫 for 'to call' you should have enough context connected to this sentence to indicate 叫 means "call".

> For example:
>
> "我在叫彼得" (I am calling Peter) or "我叫彼得回来"(I call Peter to come back)

Similarly, when you use 叫 for 'be called',  you should either have enough context connected to this sentence to indicate 叫 means "be called",

> For example :
>
> Q: "你叫什么名字？" A: "我叫彼得."

or you can be specific and write "我**名字**(叫)彼得"-- "my **name** is (called) Peter"

Generally:

- In phrases like "你叫我"(subject + 叫 + object) 叫 means 'to call'
- In phrases like "我叫彼得" (object + 叫 +  name) or "这叫工作" (object + 叫 + definition) 叫 means 'be called'

Answer (score 4):

Your intuition is correct. 叫 can be used in both ways (and even more). Here are the most frequent ones.

1) to call, to summon (using someone's voice). Verb is *transitive*:

> 我爸爸妈妈**叫我** 
>   Mom and dad **call me** (they are calling my name)

2) stating one's name. Verb + *proper noun or definition*:

> 你**叫**什么名字？我**叫张三**！
>   What's your name? My **name is John Doe**!

3) to yell, to shout, or more specific verbs when referring to animals, e.g. to bark. This is a colloquial usage. Verb is *intransitive*:

> 我狗在**叫**！
>   My dog is **barking**

4) giving orders, asking to do something. Colloquial usage. Accepts a *verb phrase*:

> 我的驾照过期了，我要**叫**他开车！
>   My driver's license has expired. I'll **ask** him to drive!

Specifically, how to decide between the usage 1 and 2. It is often made clear by the context of the whole sentence, as customary with the Chinese language.
As a rule of thumb, you'll have 叫 (to call) when it is followed by a regular object phrase, and you'll have 叫 (asking names) when it is followed by a proper noun or generically by a definition.